# explorerDenyList not working in Web3Modal

Tags: wallet-connect, wagmi, web3modal

I am trying to exclude metamask and only allow trust and uniswap wallet in my Web3Modal wallet connection. However, when I am using the `explorerAllowList` or the `explorerDenyList` it just doesn't seem to be working. Here is my implementation of wallet connection with web3modal.

```
import { Web3Modal } from '@web3modal/react';
import { WagmiConfig, configureChains, createClient, mainnet } from 'wagmi';
import { w3mProvider, w3mConnectors, EthereumClient } from '@web3modal/ethereum';

const projectId = config.WALLET_CONNECT_PROJECT_ID!;

const chains = [mainnet, polygon, avalanche, arbitrum, bsc, optimism, gnosis, fantom];

const { provider } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })]);
const wagmiClient = createClient({
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: w3mConnectors({ version: 1, chains, projectId }),
  provider,
});

const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiClient, chains);

return (
  <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
    ....
    <Web3Modal
      projectId={projectId}
      ethereumClient={ethereumClient}
      explorerAllowList={[
        '4622a2b2d6af1c9844944291e5e7351a6aa24cd7b23099efac1b2fd875da31a0',
        'c03dfee351b6fcc421b4494ea33b9d4b92a984f87aa76d1663bb28705e95034a',
      ]}
     />
  </WagmiConfig>
  );
}
```

With this code only metamask wallet is being displayed although I have entered the ids of uniswap wallet and trust wallet. Wallet IDs picked from here - https://walletconnect.com/explorer.

I am using -

```
"@web3modal/ethereum": "^2.2.2",
"@web3modal/react": "^2.2.2",
"wagmi": "^0.12.10"
```